# File is not downloading from Network when I used my system IP

Tags: php, windows, networking, network-programming

I am facing a problem in which when I type localhost/filename.zip and press enter in Chrome I am able to download a file[image]

but when I type my IP address and filename.zip I get this error . [image]

FYI, i have change the permission of www folder as 777 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your httpd.conf to allow your local network to access the server

Comment: How do you know OP is using Apache? Even if OP is using Apache, you should at least explain *how* to do what you suggest.